# error check function in bash

Tags: bash, function, command-line, error-handling

In bash scripting, you can check for errors by doing something like this:

```
if some_command; then
    printf 'some_command succeeded\n'
else
    printf 'some_command failed\n'
fi
```

If you have a large script, constantly having to do this becomes very tedious and long.  It would be nice to write a function so all you have to do is pass the command and have it output whether it failed or succeeded and exiting if it failed.

I thought about doing something like this:

```
function cmdTest() {
if $($@); then
    echo OK
else
    echo FAIL
    exit
fi
}
```

So then it would be called by doing something like `cmdTest ls -l`, but when Id o this I get:
`ls -l:  Command not found`.

What is going on?  How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like I have extra `$()`.  When I do `if $@` things seem to work

Comment: Using `exit` by itself with make the exit status that of the last command to execute, `echo`, which is 0. A command that fails should be exiting with a non-zero status.

Answer (score 2):

Your `cmdtest` function is limited to simple commands (no pipes, no `&&`/`||`, no redirections) and its arguments. It's only a little more typing to use the far more robust

```
{ ... ;} && echo OK || { echo Fail; exit 1; }
```

where `...` is to be replaced by any command line you might want to execute. For simple commands, the braces and trailing semi-colon are unnecessary, but in general you will need
them to ensure that your command line is treated as a single command for purposes of using `&&`.

If you tried to run something like

```
cmdTest grep "foo" file.txt || echo "foo not found"
```

your function would only run `grep "foo" file.txt`, and if your function failed, then `echo "foo not found" would run. An attempt to pass the entire`x || y` to your function like

```
cmdTest 'grep "foo" file.txt || echo "foo not found"
```

would fail even worse: the *entire* command string would be treated as a command name, which is not what you intended. Likewise, you cannot pass pipelines

```
cmdTest grep "foo" file.txt | grep "bar"
```

because the pipeline consists of two commands: `cmdTest grep "foo" file.txt` and `grep "bar"`.

Shell (whether `bash`, `zsh`, POSIX `sh` or nearly any other kind) is simply not a language that is useful for passing arbitrary command lines as an argument to another function to be executed. The only work around, to use the `eval` command, is fragile at best and a security risk at worst, and cannot be recommended against enough. (And no, I will not provide an example of how to use `eval`, even in a limited capacity.)

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit more?  Why does your answer allow `&&, ||, |`?  Also, Your solution is abbreviated so i'm Not quite sure what comes before the ellipses.  Would you mind writing full expression?  Are the ellipses supposed to be the command being executed?  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use this function like this:

```
function cmdTest() { if "$@"; then echo "OK"; else return $?; fi; }
```

OR to print `Fail` also:

```
function cmdTest() { if "$@"; then echo "OK"; else ret=$?; echo "Fail"; return $ret; fi; }
```

Comment: There's no reason to wrap it in an array. Just `"$@"` will work.

Comment: Yes, OP is wrong. The array was unnecessary. Unquoted `$@` is also wrong (word splitting).